# How to use MacBook as a speaker through HDMI for my TV?

Tags: audio, hdmi, macbook

I have a Phillips TV and it doesn't have the best sound, so I want to use my MacBook, which has much better sound, as a speaker for this TV.

I've tried connecting the laptop through HDMI to TV and select "HDMI port" in Sound output, but it says that this output channel is not available (probably because it only detects it as input).

Is there any way I can configure macOS to use HDMI as sound input?

Comment: HDMI, like any other similar ports, aren't bi-directional and can't be used the way you want, in a Mac, PC or whatever else. You'd need an HDMI video capture card for that (for DESKTOP computers, obviously) and even those are not designed for such use. Computers are not designed for such use. There are external sound bars for what you want, cheaper than most professional video capture cards, but that is totally off-topic here.

Comment: @ibonyun OP wasn't talking about a laptop, they were talking about a MacBook -- and MacBooks have incredibly good speakers.

Comment: Just to be clear - the 'source' of the picture and sound is the TV itself? You're not using the TV as an external monitor for the MacBook?

Comment: @MikeB Yes, this is not about using TV as an external monitor. I went with using the TV as an external monitor instead, which you might think is an obvious solution, but I think the picture quality (colors are less saturated and sometimes picture is blurry) is worse this way. Maybe this is fixable though?

Comment: @Max Macbooks are laptops, and as such they have very good speakers **for a laptop.**  They're not incredibly good speakers compared to what's available for home theater use.

Comment: Buy a pair of active speakers like Edifier MR4 or Polk T15 for $80-$200. Even $50 home speakers with MDF cabinets sound much better than the MBP 16. Don't waste a laptop doing the job of a $50 speaker, and not as well.

Comment: Mirror your desktop to the TV. Use the laptop to play files or stream. In MPC you can set an audio offset if it's out of sync. Question should be, how to get my TV to do exactly what my laptop is doing. If you're watching actual broadcast TV, well then I'm sorry ;)

Comment: "using TV as an external monitor ... sometimes picture is blurry" - Native resolution of laptop and TV? Check the Overscan setting on the TV. - I'm typing this on four feet of absolute 4k clarity, three feet from my face. I haven't seen blurry since CRTs. This is fixable... or something is broken.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This won't work. Macs don't support HDMI-ARC. ARC is the "Audio Return Channel" that allows a smart TV to send audio "upstream" up the HDMI cable to a soundbar or other home theater receiver where the "good speakers" would be.

Comment: This isn't even about ARC. Macs don't support HDMI input whatsoever. I think the distinction is important because if for some weird reason someone has a display/TV with an _actual_ HDMI out that wouldn't work either.

Comment: @logarr OP said that on his TV he selected sound output on an HDMI input. That means this question is most definitely specifically about HDMI-ARC.

Comment: Nevertheless, @Logarr's comment is clearly helpful to future searchers of similar questions (whose titles could easily be identical to this one).

Answer (score -1):

Thinking loud here.

The Macbook in itself does not have HDMI inputs. So what you probably would look for is some kind of USB device to connect to the Macbook.

As indicated by your question the TV does not seem to support HDMI out (well, I´ve never seen any TV supporting that, but that is me). Maybe the TV has some other kind of sound output. It is not totally unknown for TV-s to have digital optical outputs on a so called Toslink.

If the TV has toslink output you could add an external so called "sound card". Connect the toslink from tv to soundcard and then USB to the computer. Toslink in are getting rare on soundcards today, so you might need to search a bit. I found one that might work called M-Game Solo but have never seen one IRL or used one, so you may be on your own there.

Just maybe it would be an idea to search for second hand stereo equipment. Some have Toslink input and can be surprisingly cheap as they are out of fashion.